# what is the equivalent of c++ exp function in kernel programming

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to change this c++ code to kernel code

```
(float)(1/(1+exp(-num)));
```

I assume it is not possible to add `math.h` to kernel module so what can I use instead of [exp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/exp/) in kernel code

Comment: *Why* do you feel the need for floating-point calculations in the kernel?

Comment: I am writing XOR backpropagation network program as a kernel module and in its code it uses this function

Comment: I should write a driver that creates a virtual device for simulation XOR gate with neural network

Comment: You can't use any floating point in the kernel.  Floating point registers are not saved and restored when interrupts occur because everyone agrees that the kernel does not use floating point.

Comment: How about just using the first few terms of the [series expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B1%2F(1-Exp%5B-y%5D),+%7By,+0,+6%7D%5D)?